# Fetching the user info with `updatedBy` entity in keystone.js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, keystonejs

I am trying to get the user data by setting the `track: true`. But the `updatedBy` is returned with `user id`. I want to push the tracked user data to the element. Inside the user model execution, the `element.userDetials` is working but not pushing the data to the element. Outside of the user model consoled as `undefined`.

```
view.on('init', function (next) {

    var q = keystone.list('Post').paginate({
        page: req.query.page || 1,
        perPage: 5,
        //maxPages: 10,
        // filters: {
        //  state: 'published',
        // },
    })
        .sort('-publishedDate')
        .populate('author categories');

    if (locals.data.category) {
        q.where('categories').in([locals.data.category]);
    }

    q.exec(function (err, results) {
        locals.data.posts = results;
        locals.data.posts.results.forEach(function(element,index){      

            User.model.findById(element.updatedBy).exec(function(error,user){
                element.userDetails = 'Dr. ' + user.name.first + user.name.last;
                console.log(element.userDetails);
                next(error);
            });


        });
        next(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: `.forEach()` is not waiting for each async function to complete and also there is a `next(err)` right after that which will actually fire before the loop is complete. You also certainly don't want to call the `next()` callback at all until ALL the work is finished. For a better understanding of async call handling start with the canonical reference as linked.

Comment: So, are you suggesting to use another logic instead of forEach? My problem is not `console.log()` but the value not getting pushed into `element`

Comment: I know that's the problem. Hence the title of the reference you have been pointed at. I suggest you read it.